# choosing elements from the set of sequences in ZFC

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

In my previous question, I asked about infinite-length formula in ZFC. But I am still confused over following:

Suppose you want to build a function from a set of sequences to a set that chooses $n$th element in each sequence in the set of sequences to form a new set with each chosen element as an element in the new set.

But how can I do this nicely in ZFC? Or is this impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is a set of sequences of elements from $X$ (that is, $A\subseteq X^{\mathbb N}$), then just take

$$ \{ f(n) \mid f\in A \} $$

You can justify the existence of this by the axiom of replacement applied to $A$ and the function $f\mapsto f(n)$.

Comment: You do not even need replacement. This is a subset of $X$ definable with parameters, so comprehension suffices.

Comment: @Andres: Sure, but since we _have_ replacement, might as well use it, when it's closer to the intuition we want to capture. And it also works when there's no common $X$.

Comment: Not my style, the "might as well use it", it feels wasteful. Anyway, call it a aesthetic preference.